# Convert returns into an index?

Tags: returns, equity-curve

What's the right way to take a series of returns and convert it into a continuous index?  Let's say I want to show the performance of a strategy starting from 1, and adding on returns so that I get an equity curve, should I be using `cumsum(1 + returns)` or `cumprod(1 + returns)`?

Comment: I voted for a close, since this kind of question apprears to be too simple.

Comment: I agree... voting to close

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "continuous index"; surely you want "cumulative returns". Dollar P&L is added whereas compounded interest is multiplied. You have the latter. Now I'm going to close this for being too basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be cumprod. Say you have an index of 0.7, and a daily return of -10%. The new index should be 0.63, not 0.6.